# Netgear GS724Tv4 one port connected to multiple VLANs

Tags: switch, vlan

I have hit a bit of a snag when setting up a series of VLANs, I am trying to have one PC that is able to access multiple VLANs, but at the same time not having the different VLANs being connected.

The switch in question is a Netgear GS724Tv4.

To simplify my setup I have three computers, connected to port 1, 2 and 3.
What I wish to achieve is two VLANs (+ default);

```
VLAN1 (default) = Computer 1  
VLAN4 = Computer 1 and 2
VLAN5 = Computer 1 and 3
```

I am trying to communicate with both computer 2 and 3 from Computer 1, but limiting 2 and 3 to not see each other.

Here is an image of the Port PVID Configuration of the switch, were you can see the port VLAN membership as well;

[image: PVID Configuration]

I am currently trying to send a ping-request from Computer 1 to either Computer 2 or 3, but am getting `Request timed out.`

If I bypass the switch and connect the devices directly I get a response from the ping. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

---

My IP configuration is;

```
Computer 1: 192.168.0.31
Computer 2: 192.168.0.48
Computer 3: 192.168.0.49
```

Comment: You mention ping (L3) and given that box1 is connected to VLAN 1 (native) and VLANs 4,5 tagged (g1), box2 connected to VLAN 4 (g2) and box3 is connected to VLAN 5 (g3) - whats the IP configuration? Box1 should have 2 sub-interfaces and in total 3: (ie: eth0 - vlan 1, eth0.4 and eth0.5) and all of them should have IPs. What I want to say is your VLAN config looks OK, what's your host/IP config?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the PC1 NIC is VLAN capable you need to configure it (or rather the virtual instances) exactly like its respective uplink port. Each VLAN is a distinct subnet and requires an IP address from that subnet.

If you want VLANs 4 and 5 to be private for PC1+PC2 and PC1+PC3 you'd connect PC2 to a VLAN 4 untagged port, PC3 to a VLAN 5 untagged port and PC1 to a port with VLAN 1 untagged, VLAN 4 tagged, and VLAN 5 tagged.

If the PC1 NIC isn't VLAN capable you can only connect it to a single subnet. You'll need to add NICs for the other VLANs subnets.